# Why does this inner div show up below the outer div?

Tags: html, css

I have two divs, one inner and one outer, but the inner `div` is being rendered below the outer `div`.  Here's my simplified markup:

```
<div id="outer" style="position: relative;">
    Outer

    <div id="inner" style="position: absolute; right: 0;">
        Inner
    </div>

</div>
```

I can confirm in Firebug that the inner `div` is rendered below (and outside of the outer div).  Obviously I'm assuming that there is some other style on the page that could cause this, but I haven't been able to find it.  What could cause this kind of behavior?  Interestingly, when I remove the `position: absolute;` style from the inner `div`, this behavior disappears... but of course I don't get the positioning I want in that case.

What I want here is the inner `div` to appear below the text "Outer," but still inside the outer `div`.  I'd like to to be aligned to the right side of #outer.

There's also another `div` inside #outer, where the text "Outer", aligned to the left (`position: absolute; left: 0;`).  I didn't mention that in the original question because it didn't seem directly relevant to the behavior I'm observing.  Both inner divs with absolute positioning show up below and outside of #outer.

*Edit*: What I really, really want here is an outer container with two inner columns: one on the left and one on the right.  Floats seem to cause other problems, so I was hoping that relative+absolute positioning would solve this.

Comment: «I can confirm in Firebug that the inner div is rendered below (and outside of the inner div)»
You probably mean «outside of the outer div», right?

Comment: Maybe expand a little, and tell us what it is exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: You want to use `float: right` on `#inner`. To encapsulate the floated item, you'll either need to float the `#outer` element, or have content following the `#inner` element that has `clear: right`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is not with the absolute position. Indeed inner div will have top,left of outer div as root coordinates, the problem is laying down in how divs (block elements) are rendered when no width/height attributes are set, check this below it will answer your question. :)

```
<div id="outer" style="position: relative; background-color: #f1af1f; width: 100px;">
    Outer
    <div id="inner" style="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0;">
        Inner
    </div>
</div>
```

Edit:
I updated the code above, you can run it in your browser and you'll see the follow (I will try to explain how the browser understands it). 
A yellow rectangle with text "Outer" on left and "Inner" on right on the same line. The rectangle is 100px width. Now how the browser understands the code above.

```
First the browser parses the html into DOM Tree, so you can this structure (simplified)
body ->
  div#outer -> // position relative, yellow background, 100px in width, auto-height
    div#inner -> // position absolute, top offset 0 units, right offset 0 units.
```

Now the browser renders div#outer at top left corner of the browser's window, with the width of 100px, auto calculates the height based on the font used to display the string "Outer". Then it moves to its children (div#inner). It sees its positioned absolute with top and right. Now the browser knows div#outer is positioned relatively so it sets (top,left) coordinates of div#inner to start from (top,left) coordinates of div#outer. Once this is measured, the browser knows how to set top and right. In our case the bounds of div#outer are (top, left, right, bottom): 0, 0, 100, X (depending on div#outer content height). So div#inner position start from div#outer top border to the bottom and from its right border to the left one (depending on the content).

Now, one this to mention here. If you have more content in your div#inner then the height/width of your div#outer the inner one will overlap and go out the boundaries of div#outer. You can fix this by adding: overflow: hidden; to div#outer.

Hope this makes the thing more clear.

Note: I skipped details on how position absolute is handled by the browser.

Comment: I read your comments and I am confused to what you want to achieve, adding top: x; to inner will position the absolute div on Y where you want and adding width: x; to outer will limit the bottom-right position of inner.

Comment: Okay, so what do I do about it?  How do I get #inner to show up inside of #outer?

Answer (score 2):

As you have not given `#inner` any `top` but only a `right`, it starts where it´s at, just below the text `Outer`.

By the way `outside` is not a concept that really applies to an absolutely positioned block. You remove it from the document flow, so it´s technically not inside anything.

Comment: No, that doesn't seem to matter.  I *want* #inner to show up just below the text "Outer", but instead it shows up below and *outside of* the div #outer.

Answer (score 1):

Just guessing:

- Maybe you want to add a `top: 0;`?
- Is there any other Element with that ID in the document?
- If you copy your CSS to an external file, does it work then?

Answer (score 0):

You said "*What I want here is the inner div to appear below the text "Outer," but still inside the outer div. I'd like to to be aligned to the right side of #outer.*"

```
<div id="outer" style="float:left;">
    Outer

    <div id="inner" style="float:right; clear:left;">
        Inner
    </div>
</div>
```

That's what I understand.